# I have some questions about TCP receive window

Tags: tcp, flow-control

I am currently digging through pcaps, and may have misunderstood some things. Are the following assumptions about the receive window true?

- RWND is basically the current size of the buffer. It has some max, and the TCP packets contain the current buffer size (MAX - receivedOctets).
- Assuming the previous is correct, does the MAX buffer size change during communication? Is the MAX buffer size usually constant?

Comment: *Receive* window, not 'receiver' window. RWND is the current *empty space* in the buffer, which changes every time something is received, and every time the application reads data out of it.

Comment: NB This is about [tag:flow-control], not [tag:congestion-control].